# Marketplace Extension - Marketing feedback cannot be completed

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

I currently have feedback from the Marketing review phase which is impossible for me to implement, and I am unsure how to proceed.  There doesn't seem to be anyone to contact, and I cannot leave a comment as part of the process.

The exact feedback is that I must include a link to the website for the application that we build(It is linked directly with our extension), but this website does not exist.  We're an industry product and we don't advertise our services openly.  I have linked to our main website where people can contact us, with full email and telephone support, but this has been rejected twice now in a row because our website does not specifically mention this product.

The second bit of feedback is that we must supply more detailed information about what our extension does.  Unfortunately our extension only adds a button to two menus, and the button converts an order into XML and then downloads it to the users machine.  That is its entire functionality and I am struggling to expand the description beyond four bullet points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually after submitting the same un-changed request to the team three times, got a response back with a contact email.  If you have any issues with the approvals team, you should email marketplace@magento.com with your apps name, your email address and any other pertenant data that you can think of.